# having trouble trying to install C/C++ extension for VS Code for MinGW-w64

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a MinGW-w64 app I need to support, on Windows 10.
I've got Visual Studio 2019 Pro installed and used Visual Installer to add Code.

I'm following Using GCC with MinGW which will let me use Visual Studio to develop the MinGW-w64 app.
Hooray!
But, in step 2. of the how-to: [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) I open the link [C/C++ extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)
and click the Install button, but nothing happens.

Comment: VS and VSC are 2 completely different programs, which one are you using

Comment: VSC.  Oh!  So I should install VSC independently of VS, and then add the extension, yes?

Comment: rioV8: Hmm. In Visual Installer, I added Core to VS.  What's the difference between that and VSC proper?

Comment: VSC is an editor and VS is an IDE